# How to perform undo and redo operation on code mirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

There is one icon for undo and one for redo. I want to perform redo and undo operations in codemirror when those icon are clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple to undo and redo in codemirror. All you need to do is create a new editor.

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, {
  value: "function myScript(){return 100;}\n",
  mode:  "javascript"
});
```

Then you can call myCodeMirror.undo() and myCodeMirror.redo(). I made a simple electron codeEditor with codemirror a while ago it might help you to have a look over what I did https://github.com/davidmather/electronCodeEditor/blob/master/index.html .

You can find most of the commands on the codeMirror GitHub here https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/src/edit/commands.js